# rsync files that are only accessible if I switch user with sudo su

Tags: ssh, permissions, rsync

I have a local user "w10_user" on my windows 10 (local) computer.
There is remote linux host "server".
On server, where I can't change any configuration I have users "not_privileged" and "priviledged".
User "priviledged" is the only one that can access files on /priviledged_files/*.
As a "not_priviledged" user I can switch to "priviledged" user with 'sudo /bin/su - priviledged -s /bin/bash'.

I have to download /priviledged_files/* to windows 10 computer.

At the moment I am doing it in the following way:

1. (server) copy /priviledged_files/* /tmp/priviledged
2. (server) chmod -R o+r /tmp/priviledged
3. (local)  rsync not_priviledged@server:/tmp/priviledged/ .
4. (server) rm -r /tmp/priviledged

It works, but can I somehow do it in the single step, by using single rsync command?

Comment: Run rsync daemon on linux server as privileged user.

Comment: I cannot change setup on server by any means.